# Permanently disable saving of a model in Yii

Tags: yii

Is it possible to create an AR model in yii in such a way as to disable the `save()` function? I am using the models to display data that is entered into the DB from another source and will never need to update it.

**UPDATE:**
So which methods do I override, which methods in the base class actually write something to DB?

Comment: Why can't you just.. not use `save()` method on these models?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Override save() and just return true; Would that be just fine?

Comment: I actually never do use `save()`, but then I don't really know if `save()` is really the only place where something gets written to DB. Would overriding `save()` in my models be enough to ensure that nothing is ever written do DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply override `save` and have it throw an appropriate exception. For example:

```
public function save(bool $runValidation=true, array $attributes=NULL)
{
    throw new \LogicException("This kind of model does not support saving.");
}
```

This way it's also clear to anyone that mistakenly calls the method what is going on.

Don't forget to also override [`saveAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveAttributes-detail) since the two methods are unfortunately completely independent.

Comment: And that's exactly the problem. Which methods should I override?

Comment: @Beowulfenator: It's impossible to disallow *all* possibilities of a write being issued through the model itself (Yii doesn't help). You would need to replace the [commandBuilder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#commandBuilder-detail) with your own version that refuses to build write commands, and even then someone can directly access the `dbConnection` and work through that. Good design dictates that prohibiting writes will be enforced at the database level; the model itself should just remind you if you forget.

Comment: Oh, that's good idea. Restrict privileges for db user to prevent accidental data corruption and also override those methods in the class.